# Network failure” to download PDF from chrome and Edge browser but it is working in IE and firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, pdf, browser

In my current application, when I click **PDF View** button, that time PDF is opened in new window and after that we can download the PDF file. During download time it is throwing error for chrome and Edge browser but it is working for IE and Firefox. I searched google I have found similar type of issue fixed using browser content setting. If I applied same, that time **PDF View** option direct download the pdf file but expected Behavior is first we can view the pdf after that we download the pdf file.

```
type_parameter = "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8"

header = [("Content-Disposition", "filename=%s" % file_name),('Content-type', 
'application/pdf; charset="UTF-8"')]
```

Could someone tell how to fixed this issue?

Image1:

[image]

**Network Failed error:**

[image]

thanks in advance

Python Code:

```
content = create_pdf_file()
type= "application/pdf"
h= [("Content-Disposition", "filename=%s" % file_name),('Content-type', 'application/pdf; charset="UTF-8"')]
self._ctx.iLib.forward("display", content, type, h)
```

display.tmpl:

```
#def __call__(data, Ctype="application/pdf", h=None)
*##slurp
    #set self.Ctype= Ctype
    #if not h
        #set h= []
    #end if
    #for name, value in h:
        #if name.lower() == 'content-type':
            #set self.Ctype= value
            #silent $headers.remove((name, value))
        #end if
    #end for
    #set self.h= h
    #return data
```

Comment: We are going to need a tad more context. 
please post what code you are having issues with along with any errors

Comment: I added code and error details.Please have a look into this

Comment: @SatyajitDas, did you find any solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Rahul_2289 Hi rahul. Did you find any solution urself?

Answer (score 0):

Change PDF MIME Type in Web Server or Response Headers from

```
application/pdf
```

to

```
application/octet-stream
```

This problem is when is enabled gzip compression and/or HTTP/2

Enable http/2 for SSL connections is a hugely valuable performance setting. However http2 expects the reported size to match what the webserver reports for streamed content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but problem is, if I used application/octet-stream that time "PDF View" option direct download the pdf file but expected Behavior is first we can view the pdf after that user can download the pdf file

Comment: @SatyajitDas, in these case you can use a JS viewer that download and render in client side de PDF, like PDF.js, example:  [JS Viewer or Editor](https://github.com/JavierCanon/PDF-OEditor.js)